# What channel does a launch vehicle telemetry system see? Is it AWGN?

Tags: rockets, communication

What is the kind of channel seen by a communication system (for telemetry data) on-board a launcher during various phases of launch. Is it a fading channel or AWGN channel? ([Additive white Gaussian noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_white_Gaussian_noise))

Comment: The AWGN model is just that - a model. It simulates the background noise you encounter for space comms. What is it you are wanting to ask here?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you obviously get Doppler, so that's something that needs to be addressed in a channel model.

Then, as long as you're close to ground, you might be seeing multipath, and hence, frequency-dependent fading.

In every case, even the flat-fading case typically assumed for space comms, you don't get AWGN - you get a complex fading coefficient that describes the attenuation and phase of the channel. Obviously, as the spacecraft moves relative to ground, that thing isn't constant – neither in its phase (which might at least on a larger scale be covered by a Doppler model), nor in its attenuation.

Spacecraft during launch typically shake *violently*. That can lead to fast phase changes, i.e. phase noise, which leads to noise that is neither white nor Gaussian in amplitude.

So, no, AWGN is not a model that fits here.